# How to interpret this combination formula

Tags: permutations, combinations

> If you have $m$ and $n$ number of distinct items, and you get to choose $p$ and $q$ things respectively out of them, then the number of ways you can permute $p+q$ items is as follows:

$m$ items can be chosen for $p$ places like $^mC_p$

$n$ items can be chosen for $q$ places like $^nC_q$

and $p+q\:$ items can be permuted among themselves as $(p+q)!$

so the permutation will be $^mC_p\times{}^nC_q\times(p+q)!$

Now, I more or less have the intuition behind this formulation. But a problem arose when I tried to describe it to my twelfth grader student. He understood the reasoning behind that. But he insisted me on writing this formulation in terms of $P$. I had no clue at first. After some trial and error with some data, I found the following term which is numerically same as the previous one.

> $^mP_p\times{}^nP_q\times{}^{p+q}C_{p\text{ or }q}={}^mC_p\times{}^nC_q\times(p+q)!$

Though it spits out the same numbers, I'd like to grasp some ***insight*** into it. 
How should this term be ***interpreted*** $^mP_p\times{}^nP_q\times{}^{p+q}C_{p\text{ or } q}$?

Comment: What is the \or command?

Comment: @trisct, I think it just means $p+q$ choose $p$ or $p+q$ choose $q$, which are both equal.  I say that because that’s what makes the equation true.

Comment: **p or q**... Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm not familiar with MathJax.

Comment: Here’s the MathJax tutorial page:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  p \cr}  \right) = {{m^{\,\underline {\,p\,} } } \over {p!}}\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( \matrix{
  m \cr 
  p \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  q \cr}  \right)\left( {p + q} \right)! = {{m^{\,\underline {\,p\,} } } \over {p!}}{{n^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } } \over {q!}}\left( {p + q} \right)! =   \cr 
  &  = m^{\,\underline {\,p\,} } n^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } {{\left( {p + q} \right)!} \over {p!q!}} = m^{\,\underline {\,p\,} } n^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } \left( \matrix{
  p + q \cr 
  q \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$

That means that the alternative scheme is:
You take a first group of $p$ items from $m$, forming all possible  $p$-tuples (order considered).
You do the same with the items from $n$.
For each combination of a $p$-tuple and a $q$-tuple, you permute the items.

Comment: I'm not looking for it. I did that myself before posting the question. I need an intuitive explanation of the terms here. Why does it work? For example: $^nC_r=^nC_{n-r}$ Here both sides give the same result, but when you have the intuition, you can really make sense of it, and can _use_ this to your benefit. I was looking for any such ***insight***. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Great reply! **"For each combination of $p \text{ and } q$"**. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to think of things. In the ${}^mC_p{}^nC_q(p+q)!$ way of counting things, you are picking $p$ out of the $m$ objects from the first set, then picking $q$ out of the $n$ objects from the second set, then taking these $p+q$ objects and lining them up in a row, while in the second way of counting things, you start with an empty row with $p+q$ slots, first decide which $p$ slots will be filled with objects from the first set, then fill these $p$ slots, and finally fill the remaining $q$ slots with objects from the second set. The initial decision has ${}^{p+q}C_{p\text{ or }q}$ possibilities, followed by ${}^mP_{p}$ possibilities for filling the chosen $p$ slots, followed by ${}^nP_{q}$ possibilities for filling the remaining $q$ slots.